# Is it strictly necessary to use Urban Airship SDK on the device

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

We have an app on android and iOS that is currently getting tokens directly from GCM/APN and passing that to our servers. Our servers send messages directly to the GCM/APN notification servers. We want to migrate to Urban Airship without changing the clients at all. I can imagine this would be technically possible by having our servers forward the APN/GCM token to Urban Airship on behalf of the client device since we get the token anyway. UA only needs the APN/GCM token, so it shouldn't matter if the device is sending it to them or that our server is sending it, as long as they get the token. I assume their servers will send us back a second UA token, which is what we use from then on to send messages via UA.

So instead of this:

```
Device --> 
  UA-SDK -> 
     Get-APN-Token
     Register-With-UA
  Register-With-Our-Servers
```

Can we instead do this:

```
Device -->
  Get-APN-Token
  Register-With-Our-Servers -->
      Register-With-UA
```

The key difference being that only our servers are interacting with Urban Airship and the client doesn't care.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be possible because UA's SDK also generates something called an APID to use as a unique identifier on Android, which is stored device-side to enable push notifications. The APID is used by UA for all interactions with the device.

That's why also no server-side method exists for creating APIDs.

The SDK will be the best route. It's actually a pretty straightforward, simple integration, though: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android.html

Cheers, -B

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid updates to all of our clients, but if there is no server api like you say, then I have no choice. But how do I migrate existing APN/GCM tokens to APIDs? There must be some API to do that no?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you'll have to update your app. The good news is that once you drop in the SDK, it'll automatically generate APIDs that map to GCM tokens - I don't think you'll need to migrate anything on the Android side. On the APN side, those could be migrated using the device registration API in combination with adding the SDK to the app. The benefit of that would be no second push notification opt-in request for users.